# Alternative to d3.ascending or d3.descending that achieves desired order

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart, the columns of which along the x axis I want displayed in the following order:

`start of 2013, end of 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016`

The problem is that code I'm working with ([in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cMfZdzmhhVvgrVtjPkKt?p=preview)) instead sorts the columns in ascending order, like so:

`2014, 2015, 2016, end of 2013, start of 2013`

The code making it do so is this:

```
    var d_sequence = sequenceSet.values().sort(d3.ascending);
    var d_categories = categorySet.values().sort(d3.ascending);
    // output sequence and categories for debugging
    console.log(" data sequence: " + d_sequence);
    if (sequence) {
      console.log("input sequence: " + sequence);
    } else {
      sequence = d_sequence;
    }
```

My question is: How do I modify this code, such that it sorts the columns as follows instead?
[image]

I imagine there's some way of saying, "sort the columns according to the sequence in the following array", and then defining:
`[start of 2013, end of 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]`
Or perhaps there's some other way of tweaking or piggybacking on the logic of `d3.ascending`. But I don't know how to actually do that. Can someone demonstrate with [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cMfZdzmhhVvgrVtjPkKt?p=preview)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array to define the sorting order...

```
var desiredOrder = ["start of 2013", "end of 2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"];
```

... just use `indexOf` in the `sort` function:

```
var d_sequence = sequenceSet.values().sort(function(a,b){
    return desiredOrder.indexOf(a) - desiredOrder.indexOf(b) 
});
```

Here is the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k09pL2VingV7Ipmwbqh3?p=preview